# is there any psychological condition that fits what I describe?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, emotion

I was observing some condition. most people (that I observed), if they do something (mentally) to someone, they will tend to have the same feeling like 'the someone' is doing the same to them.

example, if person a is lying to person b, person a would think that person b is lying too to person a, although it may not. it is something like anxiety that appears due to our fault.

so, is there any psychological condition that fits the description?
what is the name, and how exactly it is (?)

I'm trying to search it over the internet but couldn't find any. maybe because I used wrong keyword or something.

Comment: You're thinking of psychological projection

Comment: @Jesse It does not seem like it. [From Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection) (emphasis mine): "Psychological projection is a defence mechanism in which the human ego defends itself against unconscious impulses or qualities (both positive and negative) **by denying their existence in themselves** while attributing them to others."